Duda sobre como numerar archivos
Se tiene un archivo inscriptos.txt con una lista de nombres de alumnos inscriptos al cursado de Fundamentos de
Programación. Se desea distribuir los estudiantes en comisiones de práctica de no más de 30 alumnos. Escriba
un programa que determine cuántas comisiones deberían formarse de acuerdo a la cantidad de inscriptos y reparta
los alumnos en comisiones de igual tamaño (igual dentro de lo posible podría ser que algunas comisiones tengan
un alumno más que las otras), guardando la lista de alumnos de cada comisión en archivo de texto comision1.txt,
comision2.txt, … comisionN.txt.
Mi duda es sobre cómo ir numerando los ficheros, no se me ocurre nada, por ahora esto es todo lo que tengo codeado:
int main() {
    string nombre;
    ifstream inscripcion;
    inscripcion.open("Inscriptos.txt");
    int cons=0, aux=0, sec=0;
    while(!inscripcion.eof){
        for (int i=0;i<30;i++){
            aux++;
            if(!inscripcion.eof==true){
                cons++;
            }
        }
        if (aux=29){
            cons++;
        }
    }
    while(!inscripcion.eof()){
        for (int i=0;i<cons;i++){
            ifstream comision[i];
            comision[i].open("Comision"
        }
    }
return 0;


Hola Gabriel, podrías hacer que un primer bucle, cuente los inscriptos, luego calculas cuantas comisiones ha de haber (inscriptos/30) y la cantdad de alumnos por comisión, en un segundo bucle creas el nombre de la comisión, "comision" + i, y mientras recorres el archivo original, vas asignando alumnos al nuevo, hasta alcanzar la cantidad deseada, y creas otro archivo, así hasta terminar...

Puedes generar nombres aprovechando la clase string.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    string nombre = "Archivo " + to_string(i);
    ofstream archivo(nombre);
    ...
}

Recuerda que ifstream es para leer archivos y ofstream para escribir. O puedes usar fstream para ambas y especificar el modo de acceso.
Y recuerda llamar eof porque es una función, no una variable.
